# How do i determine the current top and bottom row in a scrollable HTML table using JS/VueJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a standard HTML table with a thead and tbody, there could be any amount of rows in the tbody as it's dependent on the array size.

The table has a max-height and so is therefore scrollable. When the table is scrolled i want to be able to calculate the new top and bottom row being displayed.

Also I can't use jquery for this, I just want to use javascript.

I tried implementing the accepted answer for this question but it seemed to not be accurate and miscalculate anywhere from like 2-7 rows at times... [Determine top row in html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384378/determine-top-row-in-html-table)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) api to check what rows are visible within the parent table. Add an intersection observer for each row, and use **isIntersecting** to check whether the row is visible or not.

```js
const rows = document.querySelector('.row')

const rowsObserver = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          (your code here)
        } else {
          (your code here)
        }
      })
    })

rowsObserver.observe(rows)
```

To calculate the first and last visible rows, you might add or remove each row from a "visibleElements" array as their visibility changes, or toggle a "visible" class.